# Regex and replacing double apostrophes with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have several lines that need to be updated where double apostrophes get replaced in some locations and slashed out but not others.

So :

```
(2, 'Name 2', '', 8, 0, 0, 1, 'Info blah blah', 0, 4), 
(3, 'Name 3', 'A normal bit of information', 8, 1, 0, 1, 'Info more blah', 0, 4),
(45, 'Name 45', 'Info with '' in it like it''s stuff', 356, 10, 1, 1, '', 0, 9)
```

Needs to become:

```
(2, 'Name 2', '', 8, 0, 0, 1, 'Info blah blah', 0, 4), 
(3, 'Name 3', 'A normal bit of information', 8, 1, 0, 1, 'Info more blah', 0, 4),
(45, 'Name 45', 'Info with \'\' in it like it\'\'s stuff', 356, 10, 1, 1, '', 0, 9)
```

When trying various methods I manage to update all '' with \'\' which then breaks functions used later on.

Comment: Where is the apostrophe? All I see are single quote which is separate characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm, this really requires some parsing. If you use regular expressions it will really only work on a best bet basis.

If you can assume that `'',` is always the empty string in your CSV list, then looking out for the comma is an option. Should one of the strings however contain a comma after the double quote then this is going to fail:

```
preg_replace("/''(?![,)])/", "\\'\\'", $text);
```

To add some safety you can add a prefix check like `(?<=[(\s])` - but that helps only little.

Comment: Worked perfectly as it fixed all the ''. I noticed there were a few spots in the file where there were three ''' but I can take care of those manually. Thanks!

Comment: The strings can neither contain a **,** nor a single quote otherwise its unparsable in this context. But yours fails on many levels even without that consideration. It has to take into account an opening and closing delimeter, not just after the '', otherwise it fails.

Comment: @Sara - God himself can't parse a single quote in light of 2 singles as an entity in a single quote delimeted string. The delimeters are out of sequence. Is this a joke post?

Answer (score 1):

```
'(([^']*?)('{2})([^']*?))+'([,|\)])
```

This should be able to be replaced by `'$1\'\'$4'$5` and will match only 2 single quotes within single quotes despite if a comma occurs afterward in the literal.

Comment: Ehh shoot, so this seems to only be able to replace a single occurrence of a pair of single quotes, so a string like 'once '' and then twice ''' will only match the second one. Maybe it can be played around with more to match multiple occurrences though.

Answer (score 1):

`s/(?<=')([^',]*)''(?=[^',]*')/$1\\'\\'/g`

Remember, you can't change the game later and allow a single apostrophe between delimeters '(')', because that is not compatable with ' ('') '. Ok?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = (
"(2, 'Name 2', '', 8, 0, 0, 1, 'Info blah blah', 0, 4), ",
"(3, 'Name 3', 'A normal bit of information', 8, 1, 0, 1, 'Info more blah', 0, 4),",
"(45, 'Name 45', 'Info with '' in it like it''s stuff', 356, 10, 1, 1, '', 0, 9)",
"''''' ','''',''''",
);

for (@data) {
    print "\n$_\n";
    if (
          s/ (?<=')([^',]*) '' (?= [^',]*')/$1\\'\\'/xg
       )
    {
       print "==>\t$_\n";
    }
}
```

Output:
`(2, 'Name 2', '', 8, 0, 0, 1, 'Info blah blah', 0, 4),`
`(3, 'Name 3', 'A normal bit of information', 8, 1, 0, 1, 'Info more blah', 0, 4),`
`(45, 'Name 45', 'Info with '' in it like it''s stuff', 356, 10, 1, 1, '', 0, 9)`
`==>     (45, 'Name 45', 'Info with \'\' in it like it\'\'s stuff', 356, 10, 1, 1, '', 0, 9)`
`''''' ','''',''''`
`==>     '\'\'\'\' ','\'\'','\'\''`